# Multiple Touch Screen Displays on NVIDIA premium mosaic not calibrating correctly - Windows

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, touchscreen

I currently have 3 LG touch screen displays (1920x1080) connected to a NVIDIA Quadro K5000 graphics card. The card itself has 2 x DVI and 2 Display ports.

I've connected the displays using 2x DVI-HDMI and 1 x DP-DVI then DVI-HDMI.

When I extend the desktop to these monitors, they work as expected with touch screen inputs working correctly, i.e when I touch the middle screen the touch is there, left is left etc. etc. This works after I use the windows 7 tablet pc settings.

I then try to use NVIDIA Premium mosaic mode and connect the screens into a continuous display.

Now the touch screens do not work as expected. Since windows sees the computer as one widescreen mosaic (5760 x 1080) it treats each touch screen as the primary, as if the 5760 x 1080 screen has been compressed into a single display of 1920 x 1080. Similarly, it only detects one touch screen display connected, despite the graphics card outputting the display on all three outputs.

So when I touch the left screen on its far left edge it will detect it there. But if I wouch the far right edge of the left screen, the touch response is on the right screen on its right edge. The computer cannot detect that each display has its own independent touch area.

Is there anyway to calibrate each touch area for each display independently? Or calibrating it in such a way to get it to work as expected using windows 7 tablet pc settings for mosaic mode? Or some other software/driver/configuration tool that will achieve the same effect.